# Kotlin - Append element in a list from a map - Expecting List<Object>, Found List<Kotlin.Unit>

Tags: list, dictionary, kotlin, foreach, iterator

I have a list of message objects that contains keys and translations.

```
val messages = mutableListOf<Message>()
```

From this message list, I'd like to get the translations from it.

Prior to simply map to a `Translation` object, I'm checking a specific attribute of my `Message` object and I loop across an additional list to append new translations to my list.

Messages is composed of 4 elements and I'm expecting, when iterating over the `messages.list`, to have 6 elements in total

**Got:**

- Element[0] (unlock=false): Translation(message.key)
- Element[1] (unlock=true): kotlin.Unit
- Element[2] (unlock=true): kotlin.Unit
- Element[3] (unlock=false): Translation(message.key)

**Expected:**

- Element[0] (unlock=false): Translation(message.key)
- Element[1] (unlock=true): Translation("unlock")
- Element[2] (unlock=true): Translation("unlock")
- Element[3] (unlock=true): Translation("unlock")
- Element[4] (unlock=true): Translation("unlock")
- Element[5] (unlock=false): Translation(message.key)

**The code:**

```
val translationList = messages.map { message ->
            if (message.unlock == "true") {
                message.list.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    Translation("unlock")
                }
            }
            else {
                    Translation(message.key)
            }
```

I can clearly see that the iteration is done correctly but the appending is failing.

**How can I iterate over a list in a map that will append a Translation object to this same list and avoid to have Kotlin.Unit type?**

**Edit1**: Adding Message and Translation classes

```
data class Message(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "unlock", isAttribute = true)
                   val unlock: String? = null,
                   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "key")
                   val key: String? = null,
                   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "list")
                   val list: MutableList<String>? = null,
                   @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = true)
                   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "translation")
                   val translation: Translation? = null)

data class Translation(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "type", isAttribute = true)
                       val type: String? = null,
                       @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "innerText")
                       @JacksonXmlText
                       val text: String? = null)
```

Comment: @Sweeper Just added some clarifications. I'm actually parsing a custom XML file in which there are Message and Translation properties.

Comment: Just fixed the ``Message`` class :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to map one thing to multiple things, you should use `flatMap`. In the lambda of `flatMap`, you can return an `Iterable` of the things you want to map each element to.

```
val translationList = messages.flatMap { message ->
    // you might want to use a Bool for message.unlock instead :)
    if (message.unlock == "true") {
        // we transform each element of message.list into a translation
        // forEach gives you Unit, map gives you the transformed list
        message.list.map { Translation("unlock") }
    }
    else {
        listOf(Translation(message.key))
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that was it ! Was just not using the correct tool. Thanks for this fast solution !

Answer (score 2):

your `messages.map` call maps each message to the results of the inner lambda call:

```
        message ->
            if (message.unlock == "true") {
                message.list.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    Translation("unlock")
                }
            }
            else {
                    Translation(message.key)
            }
```

The else part is simple- simply maps it to new Translation object. but on the if part it's tricky - the return value of the lambda is the last line, which is `message.list.forEachIndexed`, which returns Unit - everything that happens inside the forEachIndexed isn't stored anywhere, you simply create and instance and do nothing with it

Comment: Would you suggest to use a ``return@forEachIndexed`` ?

Comment: I'd suggest to use `flatMap` like @Sweeper suggested